# Dimension of a subspace of real polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**

In the linear space of all real polynomials p(t) , determine the dimension of the subspace spammed by subset ${1+t,(1+t)^2}$

**Attempt**

Let $S={1+t,(1+t)^2}$ . Then

$L(S)= { a(1+t)+b(1+t)^2}
           = {(a+b)+ (a+2b)t+(b)t^2}
          =   {a_0+a_1 t+ a_2 t^2}$
Where $a_0= a+b, a_1=a+2b ,a_2=b$

So Dimension is 3.

Is this right ?

Comment: $S$ has two elements. So, why do you think the dimension is $3$? Does $p(x)\equiv 1$ belong to the subspace?

Comment: My bad. Sorry. I don't know what i was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

$S$ consists of $2$ elements, hence the dimension must be at most $2$.

To show that the dimension is indeed $2$, show that $S$ is independent.

that is let

$$a(1+t)+b(1+t)^2=0 , \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$

Show that $a=b=0$.